# Need to scrub my HD (maybe)

Tags: disk-formatting

I'm new at this, so please stick with amateur terms as much as possible! My hard disk contains a botched Windows 10 installation and Ubuntu 20.04. This was a dual boot system until I tried to do a clean Win10 install and that wrecked everything. Dual boot no longer works. I'm currently running from a USB stick. I'm at the point where I just want to use the entire HD for Ubuntu.

When I try to install Ubuntu, it gets as far as "Detecting file systems". It does its thing for a while and then stops. The only way to terminate the installation is a hard reboot. I'm guessing that it doesn't know how to handle the mess on the HD. What command would I use to wipe and reformat the HD so the Ubuntu installer see what appears to be a new HD? It seems like I need a blunt instrument to do this.

[image: Gparted before running Ubuntu installer]

Comment: At Gparted > Device > Create Partition table, **choose GPT** (this will automatically remove all partition and data within). Even if you have an ancient BIOS based machine GPT is preferable.

Comment: Which partition table type do you suggest for this purpose? Remember: I'm trying to give Ubuntu the closest thing to a "new in the box" HD (gift wrapped).

Comment: *Which partition table type do you suggest for this purpose?* In bold in the first comment. Should I have written in all caps as well?

Comment: Sorry. Exhausted eyes.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any functional operating system, so why not format the disk so you can have a clean slate to reinstall both operating systems?

Comment: Nmath: Correct - no functional OS on the hard disk. So, the goal here was to format the disk and install Ubuntu. At the moment, the Ubuntu installer has been parked in the "Detecting file systems" dialog, with lots of error messages. There's no hard disk activity at all.

Comment: Boot the live session (Try Ubuntu). Then open the "Disks" application, select the disk, and choose "Format".  It's recommended that you install Windows first. Make sure that your Windows installation leaves enough unpartitioned free space so you can easily install Ubuntu "alongside" Windows

Comment: Thanks - that worked smoothly. Windows is having its own stupid issues, but it has nothing to do with this. Case closed.